# Filter an excel table column by another columns data on a large dataset

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with following fields:

[image: Table Fields]

I then have a separate column outside of the table which contains a processed data set based on the cellphone data column: Cellphone Data 2 in column J. These are in std cellphone format aka 27848214096.

I would like to filter the table to only include the dataset that matches the numbers in Cellphone Data 2 Column for the entire table.

What is the best way to approach this formula wise? Its quite a large data set.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using advanced Filter:

1. Click "Data" tab => Sort & Filter Group => "Advanced"
2. Select Whole range in "List Range"
3. Select the column to filter on in "Criteria Range"
4. Press "OK"